# Get count of file types in a directory

Tags: command-line, statistics

How can I get a file count given a directory grouped by file type? The output might look something like

```
.txt: 4
.png: 16
.jpg: 32
```

This probably isn't difficult to achieve with a script, but is there functionality like this built into any of Windows's command line tools?

Answer (score 3):

The PowerShell way:

```
gci -file | group extension -NoElement |
    select @{N='Extension';E={$_.Name}}, count |
sort count -Descending
```

To include subfolders:

```
gci -file -recurse | group extension -NoElement |
    select @{N='Extension';E={$_.Name}}, count |
sort count -Descending
```

---

Edit in response to question in comments:

---

To break down by subfolder:

```
gci -ad -s | %{
    $FolderName = $_.FullName
    $_ | gci -af | group Extension -NoElement | select Count,
         @{N='Extension';E={$_.Name}},
         @{N='Folder';E={$FolderName}} | Sort Count -Desc
} | Format-Table -Property Extension, count -GroupBy Folder
```

Keith

Comment: Works great! How would you show the results per subfolder - not summarized for all subfolders together?

Comment: @PeterCo: See edited answer for breakdown by sub-folder...

Answer (score 0):

Single line:

```
oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; for file in *.*; do [ -f $file ] && echo ${file##*.}; done | awk '{fileTypes[$1]++} END{for (type in fileTypes) {print "."type": "fileTypes[type]}}' | sort -n -k2; IFS=$oldIFS
```

Expanded with comments for readability and understandability:

```
# Set Input Field Separator to new-line
# This allows files with whitespace in their title.
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

# Loop through files in dir
for file in *
do
    # Only if its a file.
    [ -f $file ] && \
    echo ${file##*.}
done | \
    awk '
{
    # Create list of file types
    # Increment every time a file type is encountered
    fileTypes[$1]++
}

END {
    # Loop through detected filetypes
    for (type in fileTypes) {
        # Output filetype and count.
        # Format however you want.
        print "."type": "fileTypes[type]
    }
}
' | sort -n -k2

# Restore old IFS.
IFS=$oldIFS
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to do that - not really. You can script them like this:
`dir *.jpg | find /C /I "jpg"`

The left part `dir *` will return all files in the directory.

The right part `find /C /I "jpg"` will find lines that has been returned by the left part, do a count (`/C`), and ignoring the case (`/I`).

And you can change the *.jpg into other component as needed. Note: This will return JUST the number / count result. If you want it to display as per to your question - you will need to put all these into a batch file (.bat) and add a few additional lines to make the output more visible.